# Python PIL - Draw Circle

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, imaging

I am trying to draw a simple circle and save this to a file using the Python Imaging Library:

```
import Image, ImageDraw

image = Image.new('RGBA', (200, 200))
draw = ImageDraw.Draw(image)
draw.ellipse((20, 180, 180, 20), fill = 'blue', outline ='blue')
draw.point((100, 100), 'red')
image.save('test.png')
```

The point `draw.point` appears on the image, but the ellipse itself does not. I tried changing the mode to just `RGB` (I thought the mode might affect what is displayed), but this did not solve it.

How can I fix this? Thanks!

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Instead of specifying the upper right and lower left coordinates, swap them to get the upper left and lower right.

```
draw.ellipse((20, 20, 180, 180), fill = 'blue', outline ='blue')
```

Comment: Ah, I didn't think there would be a difference. Thanks!

Comment: @F3AR3DLEGEND, the documentation is pretty quiet on the subject isn't it? All it mentions is a bounding box, and you'd think any corners of the box would do.

Comment: Yup. I thought any pair of opposite corners would work, but apparently not.

Answer (score 11):

Your ellipsis coordinates are incorrect, that should be `(x1, y1, x2, y2)`, where `x1 <= x2` and `y1 <= y2`, as those pairs, `(x1, y1)` and `(x2, y2)`, represents respectively top left and bottom right corners of enclosing rectangle.

Try to change to

```
draw.ellipse((20, 20, 180, 180), fill = 'blue', outline ='blue')
```

[image]